# Adding List records into container only once in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two containers in top and bottom,

Top container initially it will have no records i'm adding list of text from bottom container to top container on button click as of now its working fine,

but one small change in my scenario currently now multiple records are adding to my top container i want only once no multiple/same list record should appear in top container

say for example if i have one record placed above in top container next time even if i click add button same list record should not be added into top container either button should be disabled after adding list record or no duplicate record should be allowed in top container

somebody help me out in achieving it Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/qx69o1bd/

**html**

```
<div>
<ol  id="sortable">

</ol>
</div>
 <br/>

<div>
        <ul id="draggable">
            <li>
                <div class="qitem">
                    <label class='lbl'>
                        Lance
                    </label>
                    <button class="hello" >Add To Top container</button>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li >
                <div class="qitem" >
                    <label>
                        Adam
                    </label>
                    <button class="hello" >Add To Top container</button>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li >
                <div class="qitem" >
                    <label>
                        Rickey
                    </label>
                    <button class="hello" >Add To Top container</button>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sortable").sortable();
    $("button").click(function () {
        var label = $(this).prev().text();
        $("#sortable").append('<li>'+label+'</li>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sortable").sortable();
    $("button").click(function () {
        var label = $(this).prev().text();
        if ($("#sortable > li:contains("+label+")").length != 0)
            return;
        $("#sortable").append('<li>'+label+'</li>');
    });
});
```

This checks if there is already an element which contains the name, and if so doesn't let the user add it again!

Answer (score 2):

only add a class to disable and validate it. With css also you can stylling the button. https://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/qx69o1bd/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sortable").sortable();
    $("button").click(function () {
        var label = $(this).prev().text();
        if(!$(this).hasClass('disabledbutton')){
          $("#sortable").append('<li>'+label+'</li>');
        }
        $(this).addClass('disabledbutton');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `one` method to attach your listener to the click event, the button will only run your listener once (per button the selector applies to):

```
$("button").one('click', function () {
    var label = $(this).prev().text();
    $("#sortable").append('<li>'+label+'</li>');
});
```

If you wish to actually disable your button, you can do this by setting the disabled attribute on the object:

```
$("button").one('click', function () {
    var label = $(this).prev().text();
    $("#sortable").append('<li>'+label+'</li>');
    $(this).attr('disabled', true');
});
```